# Blogspot Duplicate URL - How to remove ?m=1, ?m=0

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url, blogger, url-parameters, blogspot

Is there any way to avoid getting the mobile suffix while visiting the blogger site on the mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to blogger
- Go to theme
- Click on edit HTML
- Press CTRL+F and find body tag
- Paste the code given above.
- Paste that code above body

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("%3D","%3D") > 0) {
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("%3D"));
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("%3D%3D","%3D%3D") > 0) {
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("%3D%3D"));
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("&m=1","&m=1") > 0) {
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("&m=1"));
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?m=1","?m=1") > 0) {
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?m=1"));
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
//]]>

</script>
```